# Can't start boot project where network is close

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat9

I've created Spring boot application. It's simple:

plugins:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
```

And in my build script:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.3.RELEASE")
    }
}
```

and dependencies:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
```

Additionally I have dependencies like: lambok, h2, webjars etc. Nothing interesting.

So in my local machine:

- In my local machine I build war file!
- Everything is fine! no problem at all!

**I have no problems at all!**  BUT when I deploy it at the server where "THERE IS NO NETWORK"

```
Mar 27, 2019 11:44:59 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester warning
WARNING: Parse Warning Error at line 25 column 19: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_4_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:jar:file:/.../war.war!/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 19; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_4_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
```

Any idea how can I solve the problem?

Just simple web application without any XML configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the xsd in your classpath on the server without network connectivity.  The XSD url is only used when a local classpath copy of the xsd is not found.

There are also [details on registering schemas](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html#extensible-xml-registration), but this is probably overkill.